# Can I change my terminal environment to bash shell using a script and then execute other commands after changing the shell in the same script?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, script

I am trying to write a script that sets my main terminal to use bash shell. I know the #!/bin/bash will call all the commands in the script to be run with the bash shell but what I want is a script that specifically that changes the shell of my terminal to bash.

for example: (this is how my terminal looks like when it is opened.)

```
$
```

when i want to set the terminal to bash I manually type the bash command and press enter.

```
$bash
```

outcome:

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
```

The problem is if I write a script using the above command it works but any command after the bash command in the script fails to execute.
for example

```
#!/bin/bash
bash
echo "setting terminal environment to bash"
echo "success"
```

output:

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
```

Expected output: (something like this)

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$ setting terminal environment to bash
[tyg@rooto ~]$ success
```

or (Like this)

```
[tyg@rooto ~]$
[tyg@rooto ~]$ setting environment
[tyg@rooto ~]$ success
```

any of the above is what I assume should be expected. Why are the two echo commands in the script failing to execute and is there a fix to this. Thanks

Comment: @KoenG. Right.  Now I suggest copying and pasting those comments into a single answer.  If you had done so before I read this question, you would have received +1 vote from me.

Comment: @African_king could you explain what you mean by _swichting_/_changing the shell_? What is your main/default shell you want this to execute in? If you just want to write a script which is executed by `bash` the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is already sufficient for the commands to be executed by `bash`.

If this is not what you want please explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Your other commands don't execute because `bash` does not finish until you `exit` it. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but look into `.bashrc` if you want commands to always run when starting `bash`. If you always want to use `bash`, just write `bash` in the equivalent file for your current main shell or change your default shell in the `/etc/passwd` file.

If you want a script to temporarily switch to `bash` to execute some commands but don't want to have interactivity with that bash shell, you can look into calling `bash` with a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in your main script.

Comment: I  want the script to temporarily switch to bash to execute some commands  thanks